# Package Layer (Data Management) tool reporting error 000814?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-10.2, layer-package, error-000814

I want to package layers using the [Package Layer (Data Management)](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//0017000000q4000000) tool but I always get error [000814](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00vp00000013000814) indicates invalid output file type (I try to add the .lpk extension also the same error).

The following pictures show the processing of package layer and the error message.

[image]

[image]

I search internet and find it is in [ArcGIS 10.2 Issues Addressed List](http://downloads.esri.com/support/downloads/other_/102-IssuesAddressedList.pdf) (My production version of ArcGIS is version 10.1).

I want to confirm is it a bug or is there any means to compress layers (in enterprise geodatabase) for both 10.1 and 10.2?

In ArcMap “Table Of Contents”, I select the layers to be packged, right click and choose “Create Layer Package” ->save package to file -> navigate the a specified location -> click "save".

After that I use windows browser and arccatalog to access the *.lpk, but I cannot find the package file in the specified location.

Comment: Would you be able to edit your question to indicate whether you browsed to specify your Output File, please?  Also, can you provide a link to the assertion you make when you say "I search internet and find it is in ArcGIS 10.2 Issues Addressed List"?  If I had to make a guess I would say that you have set your Geoprocessing environment workspace to a geodatabase where you will not be able to write a *.lpk.

Comment: Hi PolyGeo, the output path for the .lpk file is in the local, but the layers in the .lpk is from enterprise geodatabase. Since there is too many layers to be loaded in the web application, I want to compress multiple static layers to a single layer to make the loading faster. Besides the package layer, is there any other ways to compress multiple layers?

Comment: I looked at that list of issues addressed that you linked to and none of them sound like what you are describing - which NIM do you think it is?  I just opened the same tool using ArcGIS 10.2.2 for Desktop and when I browsed to locate a place to create my Output File it set the name to `C:\temp\testFolder\test.lpk` as expected so I cannot reproduce what you are describing.

Comment: Let's leave this question focussed on your 000814 error and then leave any other questions you may have to be researched/asked separately.  I have not had problems creating layer packages at either 10.1 or 10.2 but I have not created many nor used a variety of data sources but this one looks like a case of your Output File being set to something other than a *.lpk file.

Comment: Yes PolyGeo, thanks a lot for your comment. By use the output with the extension lpk, I generate the package layer successfully in the local. My situation as described in my comment is I want to compress multiple layers to single layer. If the output cannot put in enterprise database, it cannot satisfy my requirement. Maybe my start point is not correct. Is there any other way to do the compression?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just opened the same [Package Layer (Data Management)](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//0017000000q4000000) tool using ArcGIS 10.2.2 for Desktop and when I browsed to locate a place to create my Output File it set the name to `C:\temp\testFolder\test.lpk` as expected.

Consequently, so I cannot reproduce what you are describing.

I think the cause of your [ERROR 000814: Invalid file type](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00vp00000013000814) is that you have not explicitly specified a *.lpk file for its output.

You seem to be asking some other questions within this one and its comment trail which, if still issues for you, are I think best researched/asked separately.